# Generate random points within a polygon with minimum distances in QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, random, sampling

I have a polygon in QGIS 2.14 and want to generate a specified number of coordinate points within that polygon, with a minimum distance apart. The fTools Random Points tool doesn't give this option, and neither does the "Point sampling" analysis tool in the Point Sampling plugin (or maybe I don't know how to use it properly). Is there a way to do this in QGIS? I know it's quite straightforward in the Random Points tool in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Random points inside polygons (fixed)** from *Processing Toolbox*. If you don't see Processing Toolbox panel, activate it from menu `Processing --> Toolbox`. For distances in meters you have to use projected CRS (e.g some UTM) for more information about CRS see [QGIS Doucumentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html#coordinate-reference-system-crs-in-detail)

[image]

Point sampling tool that you mentioned, is good for retrieving values from raster layers.